# iOS Open WI-FI Networks Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I show a pop-up when no connection is available. When pressing on OK button of this pop-up I would like to open WI-FI Networks native Controller (Settings). How can I do that?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a non-jailbroken device, I do not believe that this is possible because you cannot open another application or execute any code that is not part of *your* application.  If your application requires that the user be connected to WiFi, you can set the `UIRequiresPersistentWiFi` key in your Info.plist.  This will leave it up to iOS to present the user with anything required to connect to a WiFi network.